# Trouble styling image with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

The website I am developing has a problem showing the background image in Internet Explorer:

```css
img {
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  /*margin-top : -50px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <img src="./images/garri_processing.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Please post code as code, not as images.

Comment: What is your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `background-image` CSS parameter would work as a solution, you could alternatively solve this by adding more specificity to the image as well by adding an additional class or an ID. Not having that specificity could also get you in some trouble later as the `img` assignment in the CSS would then be referencing ALL `img` elements rather than your one `div`.

Try something like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 exampleClass">
```

As I said, you could also tie this to an ID.

```
<div id="exampleID" class="col-xs-12">
```

Then arrange your CSS from there to fit within your new parameters.

With additional class:

```
.exampleClass img {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}
```

With an ID:

```
#exampleID img {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS should be this.

```
body 
{
background-image: url("./images/garry_processing.png");
}
```

Comment: i dont want to use background-image

Comment: try this     .col-xs-12{ width 100%; height auto; }